# After reboot, "You need to load the Kernel first" over and over again

Tags: boot, grub2

When I reboot my computer, it says:

```
error: couldn't read file
error: you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue...
```

When I press a key to continue, it brings me to a boot menu, which has "Ubuntu" and "Advanced options for Ubuntu." When I click enter to choose Ubuntu, it just brings me back to the error screen.

I opened the Grub prompt and typed "reboot." When it rebooted, it brought me back to the error screen.

Eventually, I am able to boot it, but it happens frequently and it takes a really long time to get it to work.

Any fixes?

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first/419844#419844

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same issue for far too long right now and nothing seemed to work until I found this [forum](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1883785). There seems to be an issue

> related to some patches around **TPM** (Trusted Platform Module), where it fails to perform some sort of tracing.

As discussed in the last comment in the forum, your machine might not have a TPM, but instead have its successor *Intel® Platform Trust Technology (Intel® PTT)*, which could be the root of the issue.

Running the following commands solved the problem for me (**unloading the TPM module**):

```
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/40_custom /etc/grub.d/06_notpm
sudo bash -c 'echo "rmmod tpm" >> /etc/grub.d/06_notpm'
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Is this safe? Are there risks that I could damage my system? Can I easily revert?

Comment: I'm not really sure, though I didn't face any issues myself. It's linux I guess most things are revertable.

Comment: Wait, is this safe to do? What is the TPM module and is it safe to unload? What is the purpose of this module if we're just unloading it?

Comment: Also, what would be the process of reverting these commands?